# How can I change R-Shiny "checkboxinput" value to FALSE/TRUE programmatically?

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny

I want to change the checkboxinput value to FALSE/TRUE during run-time. How can I do this?

```
checkboxInput(inputId = "smoother", label = "Overlay smooth trend line", value = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `updateCheckboxInput()`. See an example below:

**Reproducible example:**

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton(
    inputId = "check",
    label = "update checkbox"
  ),
  checkboxInput(
    inputId =  "checkbox", 
    label = "Input checkbox"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(
    eventExpr = input$check, {
      updatedValue = !input$checkbox

      updateCheckboxInput(
        session =  session,
        inputId =  "checkbox", 
        value = updatedValue
      )
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```