# How to switch the disable (TRUE/FALSE) parameter in dashboardHeader with server-side logic?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, dashboardheader

In my shiny server function I have a variable that is set either TRUE or FALSE. I would like to use this variable to set the dashboardHeader parameter disable to TRUE or FALSE. However, I have noticed that in order to preserve the dahsboardPage layout I need to generate this in the UI.

My question is whether anybody knows about a hack to set the variable disable in Shiny's dashboardSidebar and dashboardHeader function based on a server-side variable?

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56820844/how-can-i-change-r-shiny-checkboxinput-value-to-false-true-programmatically ?

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39446493/shiny-how-to-disable-the-dashboardheader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments to the question, @Bretauv suggested the answer tot he following question: [shiny - how to disable the dashboardHeader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39446493/shiny-how-to-disable-the-dashboardheader)

This was helpful and I ended up resolving the issue with `shinyjs` as described in that answer.